# Matlab Combining matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 1024x3x3 matrix `A` and another of same dimensions `B`. I want to make a matrix that is 1024x2x3x3 that is a combination of the two, can somebody help? My matlab skills suck.

Comment: I tried that, it just makes a 2048x3x3 matrix

Comment: Alright, `horzcat` seems to work.

Comment: Can you show some usage? It is giving me 1024x6x3

Comment: @Dan `2 * (1024 * 3 * 3) = 18432`, while `1024 * 1024 * 3 * 3 = 9437184`. I think you need to rethink what exactly you want here. You definitely are not going to get a matrix that large by concatenating `A` and `B`...

Comment: Well I was trying to simplify by adding just one dimension first, if I can do it once, I can add a bunch of them together, I edited to reflect that better.

Comment: @Dan I've provided a solution, let me know if it doesn't solve your problem and we can go from there. If it does, then feel free to mark the question answered. Cheers.

Comment: @Dan I've edited my solution to make it more general. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one line solution to your problem is this:

```
D = permute(cat(4, A, B), [1 4 2 3]);
```

However, this needs some explaining. Here is an example to get us started:

```
%# A 3-d pre-allocation example
A = rand(3, 3, 3);
B = rand(3, 3, 3);
D = NaN(3, 3, 3, 2);
D(:, :, :, 1) = A;
D(:, :, :, 2) = B;
```

The problem is conceptually much more straightforward if you begin by pre-allocating the output matrix you want, and then manually allocate the input matrices to the output matrix. However, once you've grasped this concept, you can use one call to the `cat` function to solve the problem:

```
%# The 3-d cat solution
A = rand(3, 3, 3);
B = rand(3, 3, 3);
D = cat(4, A, B);
```

The first argument of `cat` provides the dimension you want to concatenate along. By choosing a dimension that is one greater than the current maximum dimension of our matrix, we create a new dimension and concatenate along it.

So, this solves the problem if what we want to do is add a new dimension at the end of our current set of dimensions. However, in the question, you state that you want the new dimension to appear as the second index. A simple extension of the pre-allocation example that accomodates this is:

```
%# Another 3-d pre-allocation example
A = rand(3, 3, 3);
B = rand(3, 3, 3);
D = NaN(3, 2, 3, 3);
D(:, 1, :, :) = A;
D(:, 2, :, :) = B;
```

But perhaps a better method that doesn't involve explicit allocation is to use the trick with `cat` to create an extra dimension, and then use `permute` to re-arrange the dimensions into the order we want, eg:

```
%# Another 3-d example with cat and permute
A = rand(3, 3, 3);
B = rand(3, 3, 3);
D = cat(4, A, B);
D = permute(D, [1 4 2 3]);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate `A` and `B` and use `reshape` to change the dimensions of the resulting matrix:

```
C = reshape([A; B],1024,2,3,3);
```

Comment: A nice alternative angainor +1. Did a couple of speed tests - effectively no difference in runtime between this and mine. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Given: 
A -> 1024 x 3 x 3
B -> 1024 x 3 x 3

#### Choose your option:

1) C = [A B]; %-> 1024 x 6 x 3

2) C = [A ; B]; %-> 2048 x 3 x 3

3) C = zeros(1024,3,3,2);

C(:,:,:,1) = A;

C(:,:,:,2) = B;

%C -> 1024 x 3 x 3 x 2

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is any different to the one I already provided? The OP states that the concatenation should occur along a new dimension, which eliminates your option 1) and 2). And your option 3) appears to be near-identical to one of the examples I wrote up 20 minutes ago?